# rest7.com API convert audio always returns 13Mb audio files

Tags: php, api, audio

I'm a PHP beginner and I'm using rest7.com API (sound_convert) to convert mp3 files into WAV from PHP. Everything seems to work (api replies with "success") but no matter what destination (locally or on the server) no matter the original mp3 file size, the destination Wav is always 13Mb and the output Wav file is cutted. Does somebody use the same API? Is there any limitation within it?

This is the code I'm using

```
            $link = 'http://api.rest7.com/v1/sound_convert.php?url=http://' . urlencode($file_MP3) . '&format=wav';
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $json_wav = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
            curl_close($ch);                            
                if ($json_wav->success == 1) {   
                   $wave = file_get_contents($json_wav->file);        
                   file_put_contents($dir_WAV . str_pad($tr, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . ' ' . $song->title . '.wav', $wave);
                }     
            */
            } else {   
              if ($status == '404') echo 'File' . $file_MP3 . ' Not Found';
            }                     
        }
```

Comment: exactly the same happens with format=m4a output file